# Do I need to use p5's instance mode if I am trying to use firebase?

Tags: firebase, p5.js

I have a game that I want to store the highscores for using firebase. I want to use firebase's v9. When trying to import the functions I want to use, I get an error saying that this needs to be done at the top of a module. If I include type=module in the html for the script.js, setup and draw aren't called. Is there a way around this that isn't converting my code to p5's instance mode? or can anyone explain to me why I need to use type=module or why p5 doesnt work when I do that?

I think the details explains what I did.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Mattplot. To get help with this issue you are probably going to need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

If you want to use he `import` statement in your `<script>` tag it will need to be of type `module`. I'm not sure about firebase v9 specifically but many javascript libraries can be used either as modules with `import` or be added to your page globally with non-module `<script>` tag. That being said I don't think anything stops you from using p5.js from a `type="module"` script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P5.js should be usable in global mode from a script that is added to your page as `type="module"`. The trick is that in a module, functions are not exported globally, and p5.js requires that your callback functions (`setup`, `draw`, `mouseMoved`, etc.) be declared on the global `window` object.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
<script type="module">
// declaring functions in a module does not automatically export them on the global window object, so we have to do it manually.

window.setup = function() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    background(100);
}

window.draw = function() {
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ah I see thats why the setup and draw functions weren't being called. Thank you so much!